# how to send email from php script and from localhost I have tried the following code

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
$to = "karthik.hansi@infysky.com";
$subject = "First php test script";
$message = "Hi This message is for leave application ";
$headers = "From:karthik.hansi@infysky.com";
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
echo "failed";

}else{
echo "sent";
}

?>
```

This is My code I have tried this sending mail from PHP not able to send mail anything I have to configure in xampp.

Comment: have you installed a mailserver?

Comment: I am using mercury. and PHPMailer

Comment: both way I am trying

Comment: dont know what 'mercury' is but on local host you need a mailserver for `mail()` to work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use libmail: http://lwest.free.fr/doc/php/lib/index.php3?page=mail&lang=en

```
include "libmail.php";
$m = new Mail(); // create the mail
$m->From( "leo@isp.com" );
$m->To( "destination@somewhere.fr" );
$m->Subject( "the subject of the mail" );
$m->Body( "Hello\nThis is a test of the Mail component" );
$m->Cc( "someone@somewhere.fr");
$m->Priority(4);
//  attach a file of type image/gif to be displayed in the message if possible
$m->Attach( "/home/leo/toto.gif", "image/gif", "inline" );
$m->Send(); // send the mail
echo "Mail was sent:"
echo $m->Get(); // show the mail source
```

Comment: have you tried this script?

Comment: Yes? I'm using it in my own sites newsletter

Comment: Bro I am getting message sent But in reality message is not sent

Comment: This code is not very correct, it displays Mail was sent without even checking if mail was really sent or failed. Do not use this code, is bad practise.

Comment: Of course it doesn't check but the user who ask that question may use it...

Answer (score 0):

```
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "yourname@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "your_pass";
    $mail->SetFrom("your_email");
    $mail->Subject = "your_title";
    $mail->Body = "your_body";
    $mail->AddAddress("receiver_email");
    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message has been sent";
    }
```

You have to include phpmailer library. You can download it from here [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

After that you go to your gmail account that you want to use as sender and you need to set 2-step verification ---> off  and Allow less secure apps ---> ON.

This guide may help you [set up gmail for send emails with php](https://www.formget.com/send-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-in-php/)

I am using this script and works fine just make sure to set up all the changes. Maybe you have to add some changes in your xampp ( i did not but i don't know your php.ini file so keep that in mind).

Comment: SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 v191sm295231ith.34 - gsmtp 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.                                                                                                                                                                    bro getting this error

Comment: Do you use gmail account? Try keep it logged in your google account while you try this script. And last is your password correct?

Comment: Done bro, I am Configuring this because the employee can send leave to the admin through the apply leave form  is this code works for that any help from you.